# How to subdivide a manually stacked terra SpatRast with different variable names?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, terra

I am trying to take a stack of rasters in the `terra` package that I manually combine with `c()` and allow for anyone to subdivide the stack by the variable names assigned to the layers. The stack of rasters are aggregates of monthly mean, max, and min for a year (Jan-Dec) so my SpatRast would have 36 layers with 3 different varnames. The below is a simplified example with just 3 layers.

```
r1 <- rast(matrix(1:100, nrow=10, ncol=10))
varnames(r1) <- "mean"
r2 <- rast(matrix(200:101, nrow=10, ncol=10))
varnames(r2) <- "max"
r3 <- rast(matrix(c(2,200), nrow=10, ncol=10))
varnames(r3) <- "min"

r_stack <- c(r1, r2, r3)

r_stack
varnames(r_stack)
```

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
sources     : memory  
              memory  
              memory  
varnames    : mean 
              max 
              min 
names       : lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1 
min values  :     1,   101,     2 
max values  :   100,   200,   200 

[1] "mean" "max"  "min"
```

However, when I try to subdivide this r_stack by varnames, I get an unused argument error. I was expecting to have a SpatRast that could easily be resubdivided by variable names so that others could use the data easier.

```
r_ex <- rast(r_stack,
             lyrs = "mean")
```

`Error in .local(x, ...) : unused argument (lyrs = "mean")`

```
r_ex <- rast(r_stack,
             subds = "mean")
```

`Error in .local(x, ...) : unused argument (subds = "mean")`

```
type here
```

How can I make it so I can subdivide the raster stack again by the varnames layers if I wanted to access just the 12 layers that have mean data?

I can do it by layer index (ex 1:12) but would like to make it more intuitive by  variable names.

```
r_ex <- r_stack[[1]]
r_ex
```

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source      : memory 
varname     : mean 
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     1 
max value   :   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the names of the variables inside a pair of brackets or a `subset` to obtain the desired layers. However, the names of the `r_stack` should be set using `names` instead of `varnames`.

```
library(terra)
r_stack <- c(r1, r2, r3)
names(r_stack) <- c("mean", "max", "min")

# Option 1: brackets
subr_stack <- r_stack[[c("mean", "min")]]
#Option 2: subset
subr_stack <- subset(r_stack, c("mean", "min"))

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. :  
#source(s)   : memory
#varnames    : mean 
#              min 
#names       : mean, min 
#min values  :    1,   2 
#max values  :  100, 200
```

Comment: I am using `varnames` because I want the group of "mean" layers to be grouped by that variable. I will have 12 layers of mean, min, and max respectively for a total of 36 layers and made their layer names to be something like "January_mean". `subset` and bracket pairs do not work for variable names.

Comment: You do not need to use `varnames`, you can set the names of the layers with `names` using something like: `names(r_stack) <- paste(month.abb[seq(1,12,1)], rep(c("mean", "max", "min"), each = 12), sep = "_")`. This will enable using `subset` or bracket pairs.

Comment: Apologies as I am not being clear in my goal with the use of `varnames` vs `names`. `varnames` is a means to group the "mean", "mins", and "max" layers together so that they can be split by each group as needed later. By using only `names` then I cannot recall a whole layer group without doing something like `r_stack[[1:12]` or `r_stack[[25:36]]` which I am trying to avoid. For `subset` to work in your example I would need to do  `subr_stack <- subset(r_stack, c("Jan_mean", "Feb_min"))` rather than `subr_stack <- subset(r_stack, c("mean", "min"))`.

Comment: It is easier to find a workaround to select all the bands ending in mean, min or max, than to try to subset the layers with `varnames`. You can automatically select all the bands that match certain pattern using `stringr`: `names4extr <- names(r_stack)[str_detect(names(r_stack), "min")]`. Then use `names4extr ` to subset the raster stack.

Comment: Alright I will give `str_detect` a try, thanks! Good to know that `varnames` is not as helpful as I hoped.